# NativeScript - can't import mocking libraries when unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, nativescript, sinon

I want to write some unit tests with mocks for an app I'm working on.

- `tns create test_ns --tsc`
- `npm install -D sinon # library for mocking; I can't import it`
- `npm install -D underscore # a js lib that I can import, for reference`
- `tns test init --framework=jasmine`
- `tns test android`

And here's the `test/example.js`:

```
var sinon = require('sinon')
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

That's my `karma.conf.js` [link](https://gist.github.com/jorotenev/d316a5425b8a937945cc9a4f741e9b10)
The

The `tns test` command fails with `Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "sinon", relative to: app/tns_modules/`

I installed the `karma-sinon` package too - no difference.

I came across this issue on the NativeScript repo [#1956](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1956) where they suggest to set up the problematic npm package in a different module and then import it. I tried this, but the `require('sinon')` still barks with the same error.

I don't insist on using sinon - I just need a mocking js library. I tried with `testdouble` - I got the same  "Failed to find module".

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `tns test` command replaced the entry point of your regular application with a custom entry, and then an application package is created and started on the testing device. No npm "dev-dependencies" will exist in an application package, therefore `sinon`, being installed as one will not be packed with your application, even if that's the test configuration.

Install `sinon` as a production dependency to use it inside of your application.

`npm install sinon --save`

Comment: Thanks. Your reply pointed me in the right direction. I actually already did that but got `Failed to find module: "os"`. I saw that `sinon` has a dependency on that module and even after installing it, I couldn't make it work - got a `ReferenceError: process is not defined`, signifying that sinon expects to run either in the browser or under node.js.

Comment: Hey @JoroTenev did you find a solution for this? Two years later still the same issues :(